# How to capture PHP Session Logout for use in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session

Looking for some ideas on how to best capture a PHP session logout to use in JQuery.

**IDEA**

1.) User logins into admin.php from index.php.  A PHP session is started. 
2.) User then logs out of admin.php and is taken back to index.php (url: admin.php?logout)
3.) User sees a new DIV on index.php saying something like, "Thanks for using! Come again!".

I am just trying to wrap my head around how I could use a combination of PHP/jQuery to have a statement that basically says, "If index.php is loaded from a re-direct of an ended PHP session then display this DIV and hide after 500ms".  The user would only see this DIV when they logged out and not just going to index.php directly.

Comment: Do you have some kind of message system? (Like, using sessions?) Just set one to pop up in `admin.php?logout`.

Comment: Or redirect to index.php?loggedout and fire a message then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do like.

1. User logs in. session is created.
2. User logs out. Assume logout page's redirect has url `admin/index.php?loggedout=1`.
3. in `admin/index.php` page simply give

> if(isset($_GET['loggedout'])) { echo "Thanks for using! Come again!"; 
>   }

Where I need.

Answer (score 0):

The Session is a block of memory managed by PHP on the server side (in fact it is a PHP array accessible with th super global $_SESSION).

If you want to have a special display on your login page when user log out, you can do it with some simple ways like:

- Store messages in $_SESSION (in the logout action) and display them in the login page
- Redirect to the login page with additionnal parameter in the URL that will be automatically detected by you JS code (looking at the window.location.href)